# Regex para selecionar só números de 1 até 2.000

Tags: php, regex

Estou fazendo uma busca para retornar os números do artigo, utilizei:

```
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $novalinhas, $matches); 
$artigo = (int)implode('',$matches[0]);
```

Está funcionando, porém, em alguns artigos ele pega mais números além do artigo, mas, não captura todos os números da string.

Por exemplo neste artigo abaixo o id dele fica artigo2040827.

Art. 2.040. A hipoteca legal dos bens do tutor ou curador, inscrita em conformidade com o inciso IV do art. 827 do Código Civil anterior, Lei no 3.071, de 1o de janeiro de 1916, poderá ser cancelada, obedecido o disposto no parágrafo único do art. 1.745 deste Código.

Tentei usar

[0-9]+.[0-9]+  // Antes do art. 100, só marca artigo0, e depois de 999, só marca artigo1

Obs: Os artigos tem variações de:

Art. 1º até Art. 2.023.

Comment: 1 até 2000 ou 1 até 2023?

Comment: São várias leis, então o número de artigos variam.
O maior que vi até agora são de até 2046 artigos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

de 1 até 2023

```
\b(\d{1,3}|1\d{1,3}|20[01][0-9]|202[0-3])\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/pK1jE5/1

de 1 até 2000

```
\b(\d{1,3}|1\d{1,3}|2000)\b
```

---

REGEX são usadas para casar com padrões, no caso da minha com combinações de números de 1 - 2023. Ou seja ela está funcionando. Se tem algum problema é porque você não definiu seu padrão, no caso você quer só o artigo ai tem que ver o seu texto para tentar extrair um padrão.

Um possível exemplo seria

> Art. 182º

Tentando extrair as informações:
Começa sempre com `Art.` tem alguma outra variação? Será essa sequencia de caracteres ou pode ser qualquer outra? Pode acontecer de ter mais de um espaço ele ela e o número do artigo?

Qual o tamanho do número do artigo, pode ter separador de milha `.` como `2.212` será só o número `2012` ou ambos?

Todos os números são seguidos por `º`? Tem variações como por exemplo o `ª`?

Uma assunção de regex que poderia atender é:

```
Art.\s+(\d{1,3}|1\d{1,3}|20[01][0-9]|202[0-3])º?
```

Sendo que você teria o grupo só com os números podendo pegar esse resultado em $matches (de um var_dump($matches) para ver a estrutura da variável e como está os resultados)

---

> Art. 1º até Art. 2.046. Não tem variação de ª. Tem a divisão de
>   milhas. O º é só do 1 ao 10, depois os números terminam com um ponto e
>   espaço apenas.

```
Art\.\s+(1\.\d{3}|2\.0[0-3]\d|2\.04[0-6]|\d{1,3})º?\.?
```

https://regex101.com/r/pK1jE5/3

Comment: Vlw meu, na verdade tenho 2.300 artigos.
Mas na sua linha \b(\d{1,3}|1\d{1,3}|20[012][0-3])\b
Ele pula a seleção em 2004 até 2009 e tb do 2014 até o 2019

E na segunda opção o artigo 1 ao 10 fica como artigo0, talvez seja porque contém o "º".

Comment: vdd arrumei a primeira

Comment: manda um exemplo desse artigo ai da pra fazer mais testes

Comment: \b(\d{1,3}|1\d{1,3}|20[01][0-9]|202[0-3])\b - ainda mostra o Art. 1º ao 10º como artigo0.

Comment: só colocar o º no final na regex como opcional

Comment: ou tirar as bordas \b .. \b

Comment: Ohhhh! quem manja, manja. kkk.
Funcionou, só tem ainda o problema de que em alguns artigos ele pega além do artigo por exemplo o artigo 57

O id dele fica assim: artigo57111272005

Art. 57. A exclusão do associado só é admissível havendo justa causa, assim reconhecida em procedimento que assegure direito de defesa e de recurso, nos termos previstos no estatuto. (Redação dada pela Lei nº 11.127, de 2005)

O teste está nesta página 
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59853/divide-texto-em-ul-com-id-do-conte%C3%BAdo-da-string

Comment: Art. 1º até Art. 2.046.
Não tem variação de ª.
Tem a divisão de milhas.
O º é só do 1 ao 10, depois os números terminam com um ponto e espaço apenas.

Answer (score 1):

Estava estudando e cheguei numa solução bem mais simples.

```
              $artigo =  explode(" ", $novalinhas);
              $caracteres = array("º",".");
              $artigos = str_replace($caracteres, "", $artigo[1]);
```